# What's the relationship between org.neo4j releases and org.springframework.data releases?

Tags: spring, neo4j, dependencies, versioning, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to set up a project to using the Spring Data Neo4j library, to extract data from Neo4j database.

I'm currently having all sorts of dependency and compatibility issues.

The Neo4j version is 2.2.1, so does that mean that I *necessarily* need to use the Spring Data 2.2.1 release, or are they separate things?

Comment: You should use Spring Data Neo4j 3.3.1